# Node Multer error handling when setting filename

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I've configured multer to use a custom field from form data to save the uploaded file name.
But if that data is not present on the request, my app throws an error and crashes.
Referring to multer docs they claim **"When encountering an error, Multer will delegate the error to Express. You can display a nice error page using the standard express way."**
Is this normal and I am supposed to use the middleware function by myself( To be able to catch the error) ?
Or I am missing something ?

```js
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    let path = `uploads/${req.body.name}`;
    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    cb(null, path);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    cb(null, `${req.body.customField.toUpperCase()}.${ext}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerStorage,
});

app.post('/', upload.single('photo'), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'Sucess',
  });
});
```

I tried to define a global error handling middleware but errors happening in multer configs won't get passed to it.